# FFMPEG: How to extract multichannel track from m4v, mix it down and save the stereo downmix as "left" and "right"?

Tags: audio, split, ffmpeg, extract

just like the title already says: I want to extract a multichannel track (5.1) from an .m4v, mix this track down and save the output as separate files, so in the end I want to have something like 'downmix_left.wav' and 'downmix_right.wav'
I know how to do a downmix and I know how to split the audio, but I do not know how to do it in one step, which would save me a lot of time.

This is the command I use for splitting:

```
ffmpeg -i "video.m4v" -vn -filter_complex \
"[0:2]channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1(side)[FL][FR][FC][LFE][SL][SR]" \ 
-map "[FL]" video_left.wav \ 
-map "[FR]" video_right.wav \ 
-map "[FC]" video_center.wav \ 
-map "[LFE]" video_lfe.wav \ 
-map "[SL]" video_back_left.wav \ 
-map "[SR]" video_back_right.wav
```

And this is the command for the downmix of a multichannel track:

```
ffmpeg -i "video.m4v" -vn -map 0:2 -ac 2 \ 
-af "aresample=matrix_encoding=dplii" video_downmix.wav
```

Is it possible to combine these and if so, how can it be done :D ? I would appreciate it very much if you could help me out here.

Comment: What channels do you want in each output?

Comment: Independant from the splitting I want to do a downmix from the 5.1 track. And this downmix should be split into two separate mono files so that FL is one file and FR is another one. I now did this one step after the other but it would have been nice if it could have been done all together in a single command.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i $INPUT_FILE -ac 2 -filter_complex 'channelsplit[L][R]' \
  -map 'L' left.wav -map '[R]' right.wav
```

I don't think you need `aresample=matrix_encoding=dplii` in your downmixer. That function doesn't encode your mix with DPLII, it tells the resampler to *preserve* any already existing DPLII encoding.